# vscode Error: EROFS: read-only file system, mkdir

Tags: visual-studio-code

when I try to reload an extension I keep getting this error, any idea what to do?

Something went wrong: Error: EROFS: read-only file system, mkdir '/private/var/folders/cr/sjjv5dzj2ylfttlw4kd995zh0000gn/T/AppTranslocation/433C8F67-538A-41D1-A377-83EED07AF68F/d/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vscode-vibrancy-runtime-v6'

Comment: Hi and welcome on SO, use code snippet: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code (for your error). What is your platform? Windows, Linux, MacOS, WSL?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.